# Do I have to change my Akka project layout if I integrate Play?

Tags: playframework, akka

I've developed an Akka project using the actor model. Now, I'd like to expose some of the business logig as a REST service and I'm thinking about using Play Framework (seems to be easier) or Akka Http (more low level).

I'd go for Play 2.5.8 but I've seen Play projects have a defined layout. For example the root source folder seems to be "/app". Must I reorganize all my project in order to integrate Play or can I keep my source files just where they are?

Comment: Play is full-stack and pretty opinionated out of the box on where it wants things. Most things can be changed but at cost. I would ask yourself which features you really need to use and if you just need an HTTP interface for exposing some REST API then I would go with Akka Http personally. Also, check out [http4s](https://github.com/http4s/http4s)

Comment: At this moment there isn't any specific Play feature we really need, just felt it would be easier to define the routes to the controllers and add future functionality such as security filters. I'll explore how to add this in Akka Http to help me decide.

Answer (score 0):

If you import the Play jars without using the Play-sbt plugin, you can use Play like any other library.

Comment: If I just add Play as a library, how can I bootstrap Play (I mean run the "main" that starts Play, loads de routes file, binds the Guice beans, etc)? Do you know if there's a sample application showing how to do this properly? BTW, thanks for your response!